# C言語　テキストファイル

Tags: c, テキストファイル

１９７行７列のテキストファイルから特定の行を表示するやりかたを教えてほしいです。
例えば
インド 3287263 131224
インドネシア 1910931 26691
ウズベキスタン 448969 3325
オマーン 309980 461
カザフスタン 2724902 1851
カタール 11627 279
カンボジア 181035 1528

となっていてインドと入力したらその行の横の数字を表示するという感じです
実行結果としては
インド　面積（km2）＝3287623　人口（万人）＝131224
みたいな感じになるようにしたいです

Comment: この辺の記事が参考になるでしょう。[C言語 ファイルから読み込み【fgetc／fgets／fscanfの使い方】](https://monozukuri-c.com/langc-file-read/), [【C言語】strstr関数の使い方（文字列を検索する関数）](https://daeudaeu.com/c-strstr/), [C言語でsplitっぽいものを書く](https://hakobe932.hatenablog.com/entry/20060422/1145705391) ただし貴方が何を何処まで知っていてどれくらいプログラミング出来るか分からない状態でのこの質問はいわゆる「丸投げ」に近いのでこのサイトでは避けた方が良い質問方法です。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に質問を改善してみてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: やりたいことを実現するにはいくつかのステップ (ファイルの読み込み、特定の行を判定、文字を出力 etc...) に分割することができますが、どの部分がわからないのかを質問を編集してもう少し具体的にしてください。 / 現状だとそもそも C 言語の文法を理解しているのかも不明で、何から答えればいいのかが分からないです。

Answer (score -2):

そのファイルを最初から１行づつ読み込んで、そのキーワードがあればその行を表示するようにしましょう

Comment: そのやり方が全く分からないです。ご享受願いたいです。。

Comment: １．ファイルから１行読み込む
２．読み込んだ文字列からキーワードあるか判定
３．それがあった場合に表示
４．ファイルの最後でないなら１に戻る
５．おしまい

このうちのどれがわからないんでしょうか